# ILogger.LogError not logging exception details

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I am having a Functions App (version 2.0) and trying to log stack trace of an exception.

```
     try
        {
            processedOrder = await orderProcessingService.ProcessOrder(order);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError(ex, $"Error processing order: {order.Id}");
        }
```

This only logs the message in App Insights but nothing about the exception object passed.

Am I doing this right?

If I do
`log.LogError(ex, $"Error processing order: {order.Id}", ex)` then I do get to see the exception message but not the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from logging the error, you need to explicitly track the exception using telemetry client to get the exception details. I implemented ExceptionLogger in web API 2.0 to send the exception details to app-insights using track exception method.

```
var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
    ...
    try
    { ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {       
       telemetry.TrackException(ex, properties, measurements);
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure of the correctness of this. Logging an exception via ILogger is expected to create ExceptionTelemetry in application insights. This is surely the case (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#what-application-insights-telemetry-type-is-produced-from-ilogger-logs-or-where-can-i-see-ilogger-logs-in-application-insights) for everything nonFunctions.  From azure-web-job code, it should be the case for Functions as well: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights/ApplicationInsightsLogger.cs#L105

Comment: Can confirm that in our azure instance we also aren't seeing exception information using the out-of-the-box app insights set up.  Have to download that app insights sdk and explicitly track this stuff.

Comment: Are ILogger class and LogError() being replaced by TelemetryClient()? Anyone know when the logging issue will be fixed.