# ILogger.LogError() unable to log exception details, is it being replaced by TelemetryClient() in Azure Function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, load-balancing, azure-load-balancer

Currently, `ILogger.LogError()` cannot log exception details (e.g `stack trace`) to local console and azure console, except exception messages. In other words, exception messages appear on both consoles, with no stack trace.

Please note that other type of loggings, e.g. information, is working.

please see below:

[ILogger.LogError not logging exception details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56060604/ilogger-logerror-not-logging-exception-details)

There is no response from Azure Function team from below:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6476

Does anyone know the roadmap for `ILoggerr.LogError()`?

Will it be fixed, or whether it is being replaced by `TelemetryClient`()? `TelemetryClient` is still different from `ILogger`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#log-level

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-web-server-logging

Comment: TelemetryClient will log all kind of exception,customevent, etc in azure application insight.

Comment: Will the logs from `TelemetryClient` also be appeared on the Monitor page of a function from an Azure Function app?

Comment: are you using dependency injection? Maybe you forgot to register your Service

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio using DI, it works for information type, and other types except Error type. Sounds like it has never happened to you.

Comment: @Pingpong have you changed the log level on host.json to Error?